# Award more reputation to questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

Considering that the declining quality in questions has been raised as an important issue again and again and again, should we not award the same kind of rep to questions as to answers?

A lot of interesting and important questions have been answered already and since coming up with a good and clever question these days is hard, harder than coming up with a good answer IMHO, could that not be reconsidered?

Maybe questions with 3 votes or above can be awarded 10 points for every subsequent vote? That way only really interesting questions will get the reputation that they deserve. Maybe we can also factor in number of views.

Comment: you wouldn't know how many times I see a poor question probably upvoted by the answering rep-whores ... thinking to myself who would upvote this crap!?

Comment: @mehow I've noticed a similar thing, which is why I'm proposing that extra rep is awarded only after certain amount of votes or views. A question with a 100 views and 6-7 votes is seldom horrific :)

Comment: @mehow But how do you encourage really clever and interesting questions then? Ultimately the questions should improve everyone's knowledge and shouldn't really be about a specific and narrow problem (though I'm guilty of the same).

Comment: The *goal* for asking an interesting question is to get an answer. We don't need to reward 'interesting question finding' with rep however, we already have got those, as you rightly point out. You do ask questions for the answers, not the reputation, right?

Comment: @Nobilis I find it really difficult to find a question that I am going to classify as interesting among all the crap we get daily on SO. Someone even asked that before on meta how do YOU find interesting questions among all the crap on SO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters absolutely, but it is a way to motivate new users to the site to come up with extra original questions if it means they get the reward for it. SO is not a zero-sum game, no one is disadvantaged by this me thinks.

Comment: @Nobilis see [Question Badges section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Should we have more? What do you propose? Also check out [Great Question Badge Holders](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) and tell me if those questions are really that interesting...

Comment: @Nobilis: No, we don't **need** 'extra original questions'. If your question is already answered, new users **win already**.

Comment: @mehow I find badges a bit silly and anyway what I'm proposing fits around the concept of gamifying the asking and answering of questions. Again, an interesting question is a subjective thing and since most of the trivial stuff has been answered already, new questions **have** to be original in order to be distinguished. Otherwise they're closed/deleted etc. and we move on.

Comment: Simple. We don't need more questions. We would actually need much less now. Encouraging question asking even more sounds foolish.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I'm assuming *interesting* here means *it's a good, well thought-out question*, in contrast to *it helped a lot of people*.

No. A question with 3 votes or more is not necessarily an interesting question, nor do views indicate that a question is interesting. SO is filled with questions that fit your criteria but are actually bad questions.

I believe it is impossible to have an algorithm determine if a question is interesting, or to have the community objectively determine if a question is interesting. There would be loads of false positives.

Comment: Well what makes a question interesting then? Objectively speaking of course and in a measurable manner. Views and votes are both good indicators of how interesting a question is. And anyway, could be 4-5-6 votes.

Comment: Well, for example,  in VBA tag "the most interesting" (according your way of thinking) are the most pathetic and simple questions like "how to find the last row" or "how to copy data from one workbook to another". Even though they get thousands of views people keep asking those all day long. Should we redefine "INTERESTING"? Should we reward each of those with extra rep for not researching and identifying duplicates? I have seen those with +3 votes, +5 votes etc. I myself find the most interesting questions with the least views..ironic?

Comment: Then they should be identified as duplicates and closed. If. however, they're not duplicates and have not been proposed for closing and have a large number of views and votes, in my opinion they are interesting and of benefit and deserving of extra rep.

Comment: I don't think it is possible these days or if it ever was possible, to programmatically determine whether or not a question is interesting in the sense that it deserves extra reputation.

Comment: True, but views and votes are the closest thing we can get to. I look at some of the hot questions and think 'this is not interesting at all!' but it has views and votes so a large demographic of the site begs to differ.

Comment: The SO is also filled with highly voted answers that  are really mediocre at best. This doesn't bother you? @Stijn

Comment: views and votes do not really indicate anything useful when it comes to interesting programming questions. It shouldn't matter to us what people struggle with the most, we are not scientists analysing how population thinks, what they struggle with and how to make their life easier, etc, we are here to ask/answer specific programmatic questions.

Comment: @me how Yes, but what motivates people to ask good questions? I can ask 10 questions in next half an hour, but only one would be a good one, using my own criteria.

Comment: what would you classify as a "good question"? Why would it be good and why do you want to motivate people to ask "good questions"? Do you mean well written and formatted or something that has never been asked before? I think it all comes naturally and with technology changing on a day to day basis...

Comment: @VividD I ask a question when I have a problem that I was unable to solve myself after trying. That is my motivation. I don't ask questions to ask questions.

Comment: @Stijn My understanding is that a lot of people lament the fact that questions nowadays are pretty trivial, tightly-focussed and not of benefit to the wider community (in addition to being generally poor). What I'm proposing is trying to at least partially addressing this. What's wrong with asking an interesting question for the sake of it? Lots of people may learn something new and it will give some good food for thought for both people familiar and unfamiliar with the subject covered in it.

Comment: @me how "good question" topic is still open (see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-are-the-qualities-of-a-good-question), but what is alarming and not widely seen and recognized is lack of good new questions (whatever is definition), and I would say, lack of good new answers too. Some poeple here claim that number of good questions and answers is finite, and hence drop in quality, but I think they are wrong, SO is falling because of absence of stimulation for both good questions and answers. IMHO.

Comment: @Stijn - but nevertheless SO has mechanism for filtering questions - why, then, if you say they are reflection of real life?

Comment: @VividD I am on their site. The number of good questions (as of today) is finite but occasionally it becomes infinite specially with an introduction of new technologies etc. You can't expect a certain amount of "good" questions per day to keep people here.. most of it has already been exhausted and now it's time to moderate not constantly asking new questions. There is so much to learn from just reading SO not necessarily participating only by asking.

Comment: @VividD Where did I mention such a thing?

Answer (score -12):

Agree with Nobilis. A variation would be that the poster of the question is awarded some small extra reputation for each answer, let say only if there are more than three answers, or so...

Comment: Regarding `reputation for each answer`, I believe that low-quality questions (or shall I say easy to answer questions) usually attract many answers in a short while. So I don't think that would be useful unless there are additional factors in place such as age of the question include number of answers.

Comment: Have you seen basic JS questions? They tend to get 5+ answers within a minute.

Comment: Why is it desirable that question attracts more than three answers?